# Google cloud ML without trainer

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

Can we train a model by just giving data and related column names without creating trainer in Google Cloud ML either using Rest API or command line interface

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Google Cloud Datalab, which comes with a structured data solution. It has an easier interface and takes care of the trainer. You can view the notebooks without setting up Datalab:

https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/tree/master/samples/ML%20Toolbox

Once you set up Datalab, you can run the notebook. To set up Datalab, check https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a model and calling CloudML service directly, you can try Datalab's ml toolbox which supports structured data and image classification. The ml toolbox takes your data, and automatically builds and trains a model. You just have to describe your data and what you want to do.

You can view the notebooks first without setting up datalab:

https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/tree/master/samples/ML%20Toolbox

To set up Datalab and actually run these notebooks, see https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts.